# How do I prevent the Amazon cloudwatch agent from not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to add aws cloudwatch agent to see additional metrics using [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)

A brief review of what I did:

1. Create IAM role and attach to EC2 instance [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-iam-roles-for-cloudwatch-agent.html#create-iam-roles-for-cloudwatch-agent-roles) (NOTE: I do not use Parameter Store just for communication between EC2 and cloudwatch)
2. Install Agent using s3 link
3. Create agent configuration file [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html)
4. Run agent using CLI [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-first-instance.html#start-CloudWatch-Agent-EC2)

But it still not working and in agent log, I see errors like

> ec2tagger: Unable to initialize EC2 Instance Tags : +NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
> For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

While googling I found not much related to cloudwath just only that in AIM role in 'Trust Relationship' config ec2 should be mentioned in service section and it  is:

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas, thanks!?

Answer (score 12):

In my case the instance had an IAM role attached, but the role was missing the `ec2:DescribeTags` permission. Adding that fixed the problem.

Comment: can anyone link documentation from aws that says this is required? Also, how would one even go about adding this? I don't see this as a policy option under the role or even as a permission boundary :(

Comment: @NickBrady it's a permission that can be added either to one of the policies already attached to the role or to a new policy that you can create.

Comment: Go to IAM > your role > under permissions tab > Add inline policy > Choose EC2 as service > Actions - type `DescribeTags` and select that. Review and save policy with a name. That's it.

Answer (score 9):

"The first procedure creates the IAM role that you must attach to each Amazon EC2 instance that runs the CloudWatch agent. This role provides permissions for reading information from the instance and writing it to CloudWatch." in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-iam-roles-for-cloudwatch-agent.html)

please attach IAM role that you created to your ec2 instance first,it works for me

Comment: Here's how: EC2 -> Instances -> Actions -> Instance Settings -> Attach/Replace IAM Role

Comment: Yes creating the IAM Role and attaching it to the EC2 instance should work. Adding IAM user credentials in ~/.aws/credentials file would not be the best practice. But the IAM role should have policy "CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy".

Answer (score 4):

The cloudwatch agent process that runs in the ec2 should be able to describe the tags of ec2.  The permission required for that is `ec2:DescribeTags`.

Attaching instance role with the managed policy `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy` will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the CloudWatch Agent service is running (started)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, resolve by using below command, refresh routes

```
Import-Module C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Module\Ec2Launch.psm1; Add-Routes
```

Answer (score -3):

Solved by running `aws configure` from inside the instance

Comment: While this has been downvoted a lot, it is actually very important. 

If you try using Cloudwatch on the server this hasn't been done on it will fail with this error because the AWS config files are missing

Comment: You'll also need to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896030/280795