# Error: FATAL NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-config

I was using [aws-runas](https://mmmorris1975.github.io/aws-runas/) to run the following aws-cli command:

```
aws-runas xxx-prod aws s3 ls
```

I got the following error:

```
FATAL NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: 
failed to find credentials in the environment. SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, xxx- 
prod. EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found caused by: RequestError: send request 
failed caused by: Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/: 
net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

my **~/.aws/credentials** file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=ABC
aws_secret_access_key=XYZ
```

my **~/.aws/config** file:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
[profile xxx-prod]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/managed-role/AcctAdmin
mfa_serial =arn:aws:iam::2222222:mfa/abc@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the following line in my **~/.aws/config** file:

```
source_profile=default
```

Adding the above fixed the problem.

My complete **~/.aws/config** file:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
[profile xxx-prod]
source_profile=default
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/managed-role/AcctAdmin
mfa_serial =arn:aws:iam::2222222:mfa/abc@gmail.com
```